# How to unit test firestore rules with token.firebase.identities

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

Just trying to test rules with google login and phone login e.g. `request.auth.token.firebase.identities["google.com"]`, But I can't find any document about `firebase.initializeTestApp` from '@firebase/rules-unit-testing' package. The offical [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VDulvfBpzZE) only mentioned about initialize with userId and email. Anyone know How to test this kind of rules?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems initializeTestApp is outdated, Better use version 9 javascript SDK instead

```
const alice = testEnv.authenticatedContext("alice", {
      firebase: {
        sign_in_provider: "google.com",
        identities: {
          "phone": ["test"]
        }
      }
    });
```